# Question on popup window

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my code I am using a popup window to display extra information. I also have the ability to export the information in the main window to Excel.

The problem is, after the window pops up -> I see the info -> I close the popup window -> but if I try the export to Excel button, it throws the exception *"null object referrence"* (if I use a try/catch, the exception doesn't occur - but I don't get any information).

In the export function I am doing something like this:

```
{
   //some code .... here 
   con.close();
   session["dss"] = mydataset;
}
```

In the export button click event:

```
   system.data.dataset dss = (system.data.dataset)session["dss"];
   //then some work on this
```

I think, probably when the popup window opens it ends the execution and that's why when I come back to the main window and try the export button the values for the tables and all goes out of scope.

Also, if I refresh the main page after closing the popup window I don't have any issue and can export the data.

Can you please help me with this?

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: Are you emptying the session in the pop-up window?

Comment: No, I am not doing anything with session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you opening the popup window?  Javascript?  A link?

> I think, probably when the popup
>   window opens it ends the execution

This can't be true, any opening of pop-ups happens client-side this can't possibly stop any execution server-side.

> it throws the exception "null object
>   referrence"

Which object?  Have you instantiated it?  If so have you possibly nullified it?

> if I use a try/catch, the exception
>   doesn't occur - but I don't get any
>   information

This isn't true - I expect you're just handling the exception (within your catch) so that it no longer being left unhandled.

If you can answer these questions I suspect you'll figure out the problem yourself.  However I suspect you're posting back (and getting the server to provide the popup code) and by doing this you're inadvertently affecting your excel object.  So direct your attention there.

Comment: Yep, you are correct; it has nothig to do with ending execution. Problem was ... in popup page and in main page the session (session["dss"] = mydataset;) was same ... so, when I was coming back to main page and trying to export it was not able to find the table name passed ... cause the table had already changed in other page which I was opening in popup. Thanks for directing me to right way.